# Debugging compiler failure

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to compile an Arduino/C++ program for an ESP8266 and am running into a strange error that I cannot resolve. I am using MS Visual Studio Code, and even though I have the path to the header file for the Adafruit MQTT library in my includePath section of the c_cpp_properties.json file, when I try to compile the my source, I get the following in the output:

```
src\main.cpp:3:27: fatal error: Adafruit_MQTT.h: No such file or directory
#include "Adafruit_MQTT.h"
^ compilation terminated.
*** [.pioenvs\esp12e\src\main.o] Error 1
```

What's odd is that if I right-click on the include statement for the header, and click Goto Definition, the library code is indeed pulled up.
This makes me think that the IDE can find the file but the compiler cannot. Unfortunately I haven't used MS-VSC before so not sure why this might be happening.

Does anyone with more experience in this know where I should focus my attention?

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the program compile if you place the header file "Adafruit_MQTT.h" in the same directory as your main.cpp?

Using the quotes around the name of the header file makes the compiler look for the file in the same directory as the including file.

Comment: Oddly it did not, but then i ran the update and now it does.